# Hide specific columns based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've searched for a solution to my situation, but have only come up with bits and pieces of what I'm looking for.

As the title states, I'm wanting to hide specific columns based on the value of a particular cell.  I did find a blog that had a 30 second video showing exactly what I want to do, and even a code snippet claiming it would work, but for the life of me, I can't make it happen.

Here is my edited code.

```
function HideColumns() {
  //open the current spreadsheet and get the value of the named range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var name = ss.getRangeByName("GameMode");
  var namevalue = name.getValue();
  var scheme = ss.getRangeByName("Opponent")
  var schemevalue = scheme.getValue();

  //check the named range and if the value is NOT equal to "Arena" then hide the requested columns
  if (namevalue != "Arena") {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Team Builder");
    sheet.hideColumns(8);
    sheet.hideColumns(9);
    sheet.hideColumns(10);
    sheet.hideColumns(11);
    sheet.hideColumns(12);
    sheet.hideColumns(13);
    sheet.hideColumns(14);
  }

  //OTHERWISE make sure the colums are showing
  else if (namevalue == "Arena") {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Team Builder");
    sheet.showColumns(8);
    sheet.showColumns(9);
    sheet.showColumns(10);
    sheet.showColumns(11);
    sheet.showColumns(12);
    sheet.showColumns(13);
    sheet.showColumns(14);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I've just ran your code, and it seems to work fine. My spreadsheet has a named range "GameMode" set to cell A1 in a worksheet called "Team Builder", and the columns are hidden/unhidden depending upon whether the word "Arena" is in A1. I suggest that you use the debugger or Logger.log() to trace the execution of the program to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @PBurke!  You're right!  It does work... after you set the trigger!
I'm new to scripting and this is the first time I've actually had to set a trigger for a script to work.  Learn something new every day!  Thank you!

Comment: You could use `sheet.hideColumns(8,7);` and `sheet.showColumns(8,7);`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Cooper!  I did discover that after fiddling with it a little more.  I had a feeling there must be some way to simplify that.  Thank you very much for the tip!